# How to remove an attribute after animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I'd like to remove an `id` from an image after its animation is completed. I have this in my code:

```
if(index == 1 && direction =='down'){
    $('#slidetext1 #rock').animate({right:"0"});
    $('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left: "0"}).addClass('open').removeAttr('id');
}
```

It's not working because it removes the id before even starting the animation, but what I want to do is to remove the `id` #deer from the image and add ('open') after the `.animate()` has been executed.

so here i made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67oe1jvn/45/ . pay attection to the left image as you scroll down under the HELLO h1. the thing i want to achive is: when i get to the second section, i'd like to see both of the images slide in the view with the directive "transition:all 1.2s ease-out;" AND whenever the section gets changed make them slide out of the view with a faster transiction, so it won't been noticed that much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the `complete` callback function which is fired once the animation is complete. You can achieve this by updating the code to following

```
 if(index == 1 && direction =='down'){
      $('#slidetext1 #rock').animate({right:"0"});
      $('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left: "0"}, function(){
             $(this).addClass('open').removeAttr('id')
      });
  }
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$.when($('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left: "0"})).then(function(){
   $('#slidetext1 #deer').addClass('open').removeAttr('id')
});
```

If a single Deferred is passed to [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), its Promise object (a subset of the Deferred methods) is returned by the method. Additional methods of the Promise object can be called to attach callbacks, such as deferred.then. When the Deferred is resolved or rejected, usually by the code that created the Deferred originally, the appropriate callbacks will be called.

**OR**

```
$('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left: "0"}).promise().done(function(){
    $('#slidetext1 #deer').addClass('open').removeAttr('id')
});
```

The [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.

[DEMO with .promise()](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/YSYpw/55/)

[DEMO with .when()](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/YSYpw/57/)

Comment: thx for the quick and complete answer. looks like it's not working anyway :/ the animation of #deer is not working, but the class gets added.

Comment: Can you add html css and js or create a fiddle? Have you tried both?

Comment: i'll try to create a fiddle, otherwise ill upload the site on a free host. it might be easier.

Comment: I have added fiddle demos. Please go through that

Comment: will do it later, beacause i'm going out in 5 minutes. thx for the answer, will update everything in an hour.

Comment: so here i made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67oe1jvn/45/ . pay attection to the left image as you scroll down under the HELLO h1. the thing i want to achive is: when i get to the second section, i'd like to see both of the images slide in the view with the directive "transition:all 1.2s ease-out;" AND whenever the section gets changed make them slide out of the view with a faster transiction, so it won't been noticed that much.

Comment: Basically there are some logical mistakes. Its not the issue with adding or removing class before animation. You can close this question or accept my answer and post as another question. The answer for the question you have asked will not solve the current problem. The answer I have given  is the solution for "Do something after completing the animation". It will not help your situation.